# Pragmatic or Pragmatical?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between them?.

I looked on the dictionaries that both are used to describe something that is relating to practical point of view, but why do we have 2 different words?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something (like a thing or concept) can be said *to be pragmatic* if we can treat it as pragmatic or if it has pragmatic qualities.

Something (like an attribute or method) can be said *to be pragmatical* if that attribute *adds* "pragmaticness" to something else.  But you can still use *pragmatic* here.

Comment: Interestingly from 1800 to 1900 Google NGram viewer indicates both words enjoyed similar usage frequency in literature.  Since 1900, though, use of "pragmatic" has apparently skyrocketed while "pragmatical" has tapered off (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pragmatic%2Cpragmatical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpragmatic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpragmatical%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

The difference can be best shown with some examples of how the words are used in sentences.

When you are being **pragmatic**, you are only being concerned with the facts when looking at a particular situation, or when looking at cause and effect in historical or political events with emphasis on the practical lessons to be learned from them.

"Being pragmatic, Jennifer has ignored opinion and conjecture whilst looking at the full hard facts backed up by eye witness accounts."

The word *pragmatical* describes a person, book or report giving information gained using a pragmatic approach.  A person, book or report is  **pragmatical** when indicating knowledge of actual facts or indicating to others the lessons to be learned from historical or political events in order for future wrong outcomes to be prevented.

"The work, which is thus a pragmatical chronicle of the atrocities that have happened to mankind, has..."

So in relation to pragmatism

- an approach to seeking information is **pragmatic**
- a person, book or report is **pragmatical**